# Keeping anchor bookmark in the page without moving to the bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to use an anchor as a bookmark without actually moving the page. The bookmarking is handled through JavaScript.

What I want is to keep the '#bookmark-id' in the url but I don't want the page to automatically scroll to the object.

I've tried

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This works in stopping the page scroll but it does not preserve the the anchor in the url.

I've also tried

```
return false;
```

This works the same as preventDefault()

Is this behavior even possible?

Comment: In the worst case, you could temporarily remove the ID of the element.

Comment: This won't work since it need to return to it's original state. I do not want to use a timer to trigger it back.

Comment: I might append a label to the ID of the object to make it not match but unfortuantely this will not work if the page is loaded with the bookmark in the url ... and I do not want to have to modify the html document